# Why isn't Lookup treated like other symbols?

Tags: functions, programming, upvalues

With Mathematica 10, I wanted to overload `Lookup` using `TagSetDelayed`, but it doesn't work. For instance, if I define two objects with head `TempHead`

```
t1 = TempHead[a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3];
t2 = TempHead[c -> 3, d -> 4, e -> 5];
```

I can overload `Plus` as usual:

```
TempHead /: Plus[t1_TempHead, t2_TempHead] := TempHead @@ Join[List @@ t1, List @@ t2]
```

So:

```
t1 + t2
(* TempHead[a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, c -> 3, d -> 4, e -> 5] *)
```

But, if I do the same thing with Lookup, it doesn't work:

```
TempHead /: Lookup[t1_TempHead, t2_TempHead] := TempHead @@ Join[List @@ t1, List @@ t2]
Lookup[t1,t2]
(* Lookup::invrp: The argument TempHead[a->1,b->2,c->3] is not a valid Association or a list. >> *)
```

Further, you cannot even use `Unprotect` to overload `Lookup`. I thought this was a bug, but when I reported it to Wolfram, they said `Lookup` was designed to give an error on all objects that aren't `Associations`. Certainly there are Mathematica functions that give errors (e.g. `Part`, when you try to access outside the length of a `List`), but you can usually still overload them. Does anyone know if there is a good reason for implementing `Lookup` this way? It seems to break with the "Everything is an expression" principle that Wolfram is always touting. Are there other symbols that act like `Lookup`?

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what ´TempHead /: Lookup[t1_TempHead, t2_TempHead]´ actually does (which caused some confusion for RunnyKine and m_goldberg, see below): It adds a definition to (the UpValues) of ´TempHead´, not to ´Lookup´. That's why unprotecting ´Lookup´ doesn't help of course.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Warning: Modifying a built-in function is not advised**

As @m_goldberg already stated, `Lookup` has `Attributes` `HoldAllComplete`, so a workaround will be to remove this `Attribute`:

**Edit**: As per m_goldberg's recommendation

```
attr = Attributes[Lookup];
Attributes[Lookup] = {};
```

Now

```
t1 = TempHead[a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3];
t2 = TempHead[c -> 3, d -> 4, e -> 5];

TempHead /: Lookup[t1_TempHead, t2_TempHead] := TempHead @@ Join[List @@ t1, List @@ t2]
```

Finally:

```
Lookup[t1, t2]
```

Gives the desired output:

> TempHead[a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, c -> 3, d -> 4, e -> 5]

Remember to restore the `Attributes` when you're done

```
Attributes[Lookup] = attr;
```

Comment: Don't you think removing `HoldAllComplete` is dangerous to the normal functioning of `LookUp`?

Comment: @m_goldberg Well, `Unprotecting` any built-in function and modifying it is "dangerous" to the normal functionality of that function :)

Comment: Then I think you have a responsibility to th readers of your answer to warn them of the possible pitfalls.

Comment: @m_goldberg, I have added that disclosure but I need you to clarify something for me. Is this question by itself not assuming a modification of a built-in function? If so, shouldn't the OP add that disclosure?

Comment: I don't think the OP contemplated modifying any built-in functions. He seems unaware of the difference between standard evaluation and non-standard evaluation, so he thought creating up-values, which does not involve modifying built-ins, would work. Modifying `Lookup` may be required, but it was not assumed a priori.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16570/discussion-between-m-goldberg-and-runnykine).

Comment: The OP clearly states: "I wanted to overload `Lookup` using `TagSetDelayed.`

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback, folks. Indeed, I do not wish to use `Unprotect`, but rather define `UpValues` associated with `TempHead`. In the end, I decided to just use a symbol other than `Lookup`. Mostly, I was surprised with `Lookup` acting differently from most other symbols. The answer, of course, is `HoldAllComplete`, as pointed out. Adding this attribute does seem like a strange decision by Wolfram (at least to me).

Answer (score 8):

`Lookup` has the attribute `HoldAllComplete`, which means the kernel evaluator will not see its arguments and, therefore, will not look at its up-values.